# How to send email from Uncaught Excepetion Handler?

Tags: android

I am implementing Uncaught Exception Handler for trace my app's crash report and send mail to me.But i can't send mail form my exception handler.my Uncaught Exception Handler name is TopExceptionHandler.I am using this code in  TopExceptionHandler.java

```
public class TopExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

private Activity app = null;

public TopExceptionHandler(Activity app)
{
this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
this.app = app;


}



@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
{

    StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
    String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
    report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
    report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

    // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
    // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
    report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if(cause != null) {
    report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
    arr = cause.getStackTrace();
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
    report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
    }
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";

    Log.v("report", report);

    try {
    FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput(
    "stack.trace", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    trace.write(report.getBytes());
    trace.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    // ...
    }




    sendEmail(report);




    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);


}


private void sendEmail(String report)
{

    try{
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    String subject = "Error report";
    String body =
    "Mail this to sivaraj@onederr.com: "+
    "\n\n"+
    report+
    "\n\n"; 

    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
    new String[] {"sivaraj@onederr.com"});
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, report);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hai");
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

    app.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("sendmail", e.toString());
    }
}



@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
if (Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().equals(this))
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(defaultUEH);
super.finalize();
}
```

}

CrashreportActivity.java

```
public class CrashreportActivity extends Activity {

     protected TopExceptionHandler mDamageReport = new TopExceptionHandler(this);
     String len=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new TopExceptionHandler(this));

        for(int i=0;i<len.length();i++)
        {
            Log.v("error", ""+i);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: @i can't send email.why i can't send email to me.

Comment: this is a bit vague. not being in your head impeach me from guessing what happens when you run this. do you have any clue a part from "it does not work" ? like, a stack trace somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to do something in the body of uncaughtException it always fails. So I use AlarmManager to raise an Activity after the application closes. In this way, you can send an email, or reactivate your application with the content of the mail and an error and restart notification.